# Reference Sum Across Row of Pandas df

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe where one column is a current reference value. The rest of the columns are delta values over time of the reference value. Is there a fast (faster than a for loop, only way I can think to do it now) of calculating the total in each of the delta columns?

Input:

| Reference | Delta | Delta2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | -1 | 3 |
| 12 | 5 | -2 |

Desired Output:

| Reference | Delta | Delta2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 | 6 |
| 12 | 17 | 10 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `Reference` as the index temporarily, add its values to rest of the dataframe and reset the index back:

```
df.set_index("Reference").add(df.Reference.values, axis=0).reset_index()
```

(`axis=0` enables column-wise addition)

to get

```
   Reference  Delta  Delta2
0          3      2       6
1         12     17      10
```

Answer (score 1):

A second method is to create a 2D array that you can simply add to the respective columns of your dataframe.

Here is a solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Reference': [3., 12.], 'Delta1': [-1., 5.], 'Delta2': [3., -2.]})
print(df)

reference_values = np.array(df['Reference'], dtype=float)
reference_values = reference_values.repeat(2).reshape(-1, 2)
df[['Delta1', 'Delta2']] += reference_values
print(df)
```